# Adding a row in UITableView with an animation in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, rows

I have a `UITableView` that has a first row containing a `UISwitch`. If the switch is on, the table only contains that first row, if the switch is off, the table should have another row.

I want the tableview to add the 2nd row when the switch is flicked off, and I want that the row gets added with an animation, and without using `tableView,reloadData()`, because it has no animation.

I tried using `tableView.insertRows(...)` between `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` but it keeps crashing.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Here is the code:

```
class ChoicesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var votersTableView: UITableView!

var forAllVoters: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        votersTableView.reloadData()
        //when I replace the previous line with the 3 following lines, i get the crash
       //votersTableView.beginUpdates()
       //votersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .top)
       //votersTableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    votersTableView.dataSource = self
}


//TableView setup:
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SuperCell1", for: indexPath)
            let allVotersSwitch = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UISwitch
            allVotersSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didEditAllVoters(_:)), for: .allEvents)
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SuperCell2", for: indexPath)
        }
    return cell
}

@objc func didEditAllVoters(_ s: UISwitch) {
    self.forAllVoters = s.isOn
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (forAllVoters ? 1 : 2)
}
}
```

(Note that the contents of the cells are added in Interface Builder)

And here's the crash info, that I get when i use the commented lines, and after i turn off the switch:

> 2018-06-20 19:09:08.678204+0300 Shares[4670:129408] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3694.4.18/ UITableView.m:1950
>
> 2018-06-20 19:09:08.711010+0300 Shares[4670:129408] 
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

```
*** First throw call stack:
(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107d7a1cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001043b9f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107d7f362 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
3   Foundation                          0x0000000103e5e089 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
4   UIKit                               0x0000000104aa5932 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 19406
5   UIKit                               0x0000000104abff65 -[UITableView endUpdates] + 75
6   Shares                              0x0000000103a8d8f5 _T06Shares9ChoicesVCC12forAllVotersSbfW + 645
7   Shares                              0x0000000103a8dadb _T06Shares9ChoicesVCC12forAllVotersSbfs + 235
8   Shares                              0x0000000103a91554 _T06Shares9ChoicesVCC16didEditAllVotersySo8UISwitchCF + 84
9   Shares                              0x0000000103a915ac _T06Shares9ChoicesVCC16didEditAllVotersySo8UISwitchCFTo + 60
10  UIKit                               0x000000010498a9bd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
11  UIKit                               0x0000000104b01183 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
12  UIKit                               0x0000000104b014a0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
13  UIKit                               0x0000000104b01614 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 822
14  UIKit                               0x000000010562df29 -[UISwitchModernVisualElement sendStateChangeActions] + 73
15  UIKit                               0x0000000104ffe717 -[UISwitchMVEGestureTrackingSession _sendStateChangeActionsIfNecessary] + 63
16  UIKit                               0x000000010562e612 -[UISwitchModernVisualElement _handleLongPressWithGestureLocationInBounds:gestureState:] + 796
17  UIKit                               0x0000000104f76b8b -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] + 57
18  UIKit                               0x0000000104f7fa13 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 109
19  UIKit                               0x0000000104f7d2be _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 307
20  UIKit                               0x0000000104f7c52a -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 1002
21  UIKit                               0x0000000104f6188d _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1306
22  UIKit                               0x0000000104f61327 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 484
23  UIKit                               0x0000000104f603d3 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 288
24  UIKit                               0x0000000104a0045c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4102
25  UIKit                               0x00000001049a5802 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
26  UIKit                               0x00000001052d7a50 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
27  UIKit                               0x00000001052da5b7 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
28  UIKit                               0x00000001052da9bb __handleEventQueueInternal + 6985
29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107d1d2b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107dbcd31 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107d01c6b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 267
32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107d011ff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
33  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107d00a89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
34  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a4d69c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
35  UIKit                               0x0000000104988d30 UIApplicationMain + 159
36  Shares                              0x0000000103a938b7 main + 55
37  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108ea3d81 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

And a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` note.

Comment: "I tried using" Don't talk _about_ your code. _Show_ your code. Inserting a row without first inserting new data into the model is a sure recipe for a crash. You didn't show the code _or_ the crash info, so it's impossible to help.

Comment: @matt Okay, i updated it with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do, but I'm sure there's a better  way of doing it.

Here's what i modified:

```
var forAllVoters: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        votersTableView.beginUpdates()
        votersTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .top)
        votersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .top)
        votersTableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

Comment: This does not add a row. This is an odd way to reload a row.

Comment: Yeah i know, bs i couldn't figure out any other way.